# Why Javascript is used in MongoDB or CouchDB instead of other languages such as Java, C++?

Tags: java, javascript, c++, mongodb, couchdb

My understanding of the Javascript so far has been that it is a client-side language that capture events and makes a web-page dynamic.

But on reading the comparison between MongoDB, and CouchDB (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB ) I noticed that both are using JS. This makes me wonder the reason behind the choice of JS over other conventional languages.

I guess I am trying to understand the role of JS and its advantages over other languages.

Update: I am not asking about the languages/drivers supported by the two dbs. The comparison says--"Both CouchDB and MongoDB make use of Javascript.  CouchDB uses Javascript extensively including in the building of views ....MongoDB also supports running arbitrary javascript functions server-side and uses javascript for map/reduce operations."

My lack of understanding pertains to why is JS being used at all for the backend work. Why is it preferred for building views in CouchDB, or for using map/reduce operations? Why C/C++ or Java were not used? What are the advantages in using JS for such back-end work?

Answer:To summarize answers on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/121411/41398 . MongoDB and other NoSQL dbs are using SpiderMonkey to execute server-side JS functions. Here is the wikipedia's link to spidermonkey- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_(JavaScript_engine)

PS: If somebody feels like down-voting the question, please do put a comment to explain the reason.

Comment: I feel like posting this link: http://javascript.crockford.com/javascript.html

Comment: Another 2 good links--first, pointed by @Yannis Rizos - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages ; another one is Comparison of server side JS solutions- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading this one. This explains nicely why server side JS- http://stackoverflow.com/q/691317/847954 . Thanks @Joel Coehoorn

Comment: "One team at google built out Rhino on Rails, which is an MVC framework like Ruby on Rails which is written in javascript(JS) and runs on Rhino a JS interpreter for the Java VM. In this case they had a requirement to use the Java VM, but wanted to get a language which was fast (JS is fast), supported duck typing, and was flexible.

Another eg is something like CouchDB, a document oriented db which uses json as it's transport format and javascript as it's query & index lang. They wanted the db to be as web native as possible." http://stackoverflow.com/q/691332/847954, thanks @rabble

Comment: Another good one from @Will Hartung "Rhino, which is Mozillas Javascript system for Java, compiles Javascript in to Java byte codes, which the JVM can choose to JIT. ....Finally, JS is probably the singular language that has the most money pointing at it right now in terms of implementations. From Apple, Mozilla, Google, and even Microsoft as well as the efforts to make it an even more advanced language (i.e. basically a Scheme with Algol syntax sans macros)" http://stackoverflow.com/q/459379/847954

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's the language they chose?

- It's (reasonably) dynamic.
- Functions can be passed around.
- Open, embeddable implementations exist.
- It's ubiquitous.
- Using JSONy data model.

There aren't a lot of *great* options for "live" evaluation (IMO): Lua, Scheme-y things, and JS are probably the best choices for C programs.

If it had been written in Java, there is a default scripting layer "built in".

Comment: well there were earlier 3 vote ups and then there 2 now. my reputation increased to 82 and now it is 80. ouch... it hurts. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The issue with many languages is a lack of sandboxing (being able to do 'rm -rf /' in a map function is considered a problem), javascript, because of its browser roots, has one. Javascript is the default view server in CouchDB but the protocol is documented and other language bindings exist (Ruby, Python, etc). It also ships with a native Erlang option.

There's also an elegance to using the same language at the back-end as the front-end but CouchDB doesn't force you into a language choice, it just ships with a solid Javascript view engine.

Details on the view server protocol, and links to alternate implementations, here:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server

Answer (score 3):

javascript is used in couchdb only for building views and map reduce, the couchdb core was writing using erlang, javascript is used only when performance isn't so important (actually you can write your views using earlang and get a bit better performance)...why they used javascript?...

1) couchdb use json as data share format..json is really light, very fast and readable...and it use javascript..this is the biggest point..for work with json the better language obviously is javascript

2)javascript is widely adopted in the web programming world..the main target for couchdb..so..if you program in ruby,python,php,java, for web development must have some javascript's knowledge

3)if you look your view code..is should be similar to that written in java or c++, the sintax came from C...for create views you don't need OOP or interfaces....

that is!..

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question...why would anyone vote you down for that?

Just to clarify, JavaScript is one of several languages that are supported by MongoDB. Other languages that are supported include:

- C
- C++
- Erlang
- Haskell
- Java
- .NET (C# F#, PowerShell, etc)
- Perl
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby
- Scala

And a whole bunch more.

You can review this list and find out which clients are available from where by going to:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers

I hope that helps shed some light on your original question.

Comment: thanks for the response. well, my sense so far has been that admins/senior members want to discourage amateurs on this forum, and are critical of posts that reflect poor understanding. since i knew that my understanding in the matter is poor, i was apprehensive of getting voted down.

Comment: @startup007 It has zero to do with "discouraging amateurs". It's not a great fit to the SO format, as the only people that could answer it are the devs. It'd be more appropriate on, say, programmers.stackexchange. Note that nobody has downvoted it, or voted to close.

Comment: if it supports Java and Scala, wont it support any other JVM based language aswell (just like it is for .NET)?

Comment: OP is asking about the "built-in" language, not languages that have Mongo libraries.

Comment: Many think JavaScript is a pet language, but it is unbelievably dynamic. A friend of mine says: It is developed by the military :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good evaluation of why javascript is being so widely adopted.: http://drdobbs.com/web-development/231901465

Comment: thank you for your answer. I looked at the post I understand the crux behind its importance as listed in the link, which is "The prime reason for its adoption is portability. Every browser supports JavaScript and supports it well.". However, how does being portable on browsers valuable for backend stuff? Where does the role of running on browser come into the picture for the database layer?

Comment: The article notes that browser portability is only one aspect of javascript's portability. There are also numerous execution engines vying for supremacy. You can get a *good* javascript engine for nothing, so it is easy to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is written in C/C++. From JS they take the same model used by JSON to store the DB entries.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right question to ask would be "Why shouldn't it?".

Javascript is a powerful language.

But I guess one of the important factors for chosing it was that *everyone* knows (at least some of) it. When you develop a system and you want it to be succesful, you don't want to have "complicated" languages for simple operations like map/reduce. 
Look at the use cases of MongoDb, most of them are web-related. The sad truth is that "web developers" often don't know or don't want to code in C++ or Java, they know PHP and javascript. So, why should someone want to use *those evil things* (I'm sarcastic here) when javascript works too?

Facebook is written in PHP (and then transformed by a proprietary code translator to C++). That isn't so beceause it's the best technical choice, but because:

- it's damn easy
- everyone knows it
- it allows fast development cycles

These are commercial reasons.

*(and now, for your own satisfaction, you can downvote me for answering your question with another question.)*

Comment: why would i downvote your answer? but if i had to hypothetically, then i would have given my reason. criticism is good as long as it is healthy and it helps to improve the entity being criticized. without explanation downvoting doesn't tell me a thing. i'm here to learn and hope that experts come here with the intention to share their knowledge, and not to vent out their frustration on the naivety of the person asking a question.

Comment: @startup007, actually that last sentence was ironic. (technically answering a question with another question isn't "allowed")