# Why is javascript not preferred for server side scripting?

Tags: javascript

we all know that javascript can be used for server side scripting also.but till now I have not seen any practical example or a project based solely on javascript for server side.

> Node.js qualifies but Node.js is a software platform that is used to
>   build scalable network (especially server-side) applications.

**My question is why javascript is not preferred for server side scripting? Does it have any drawbacks?**

Comment: andrew barber:dont you think it was too early to put on hold?

Comment: I agree, the title was the only thing misleading, BUT he does have a question at the end.

Comment: Since i can not post and answer now, here is what i have found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691307/server-side-javascript-why When i am able to answer, if this is correct, please mark it. Thanks!

Comment: @EliteGamer thanks for the response,i will have a look at it.and also i do think moderators misuse their close or put on hold votes.

Comment: You are welcome. I am not really sure about the misusing their authority (in some cases maybe), but he might have a good reason to. I try to keep an open mind about it. Maybe sometime late this will be removed from onhold.

Comment: @Mrcoder you should probably share more than just your conclusions in such questions. Don't start with `as we all know its not preferred`... It alienates a certain set of people who might have different ideas regarding a topic. In my opinion, it is as preferred as any other language, today.

Comment: Andrew Barber and @loxxy I do understand where you are coming from, but he does have a question at the end. This question is `NOT` based only on OPINION, because there are practical uses to use javascript or not. Opinion does `NOT` matter in this case. He specifically asks are there any drawbacks. Basically what are the `PROS` and `CONS`.

Comment: This is more of a discussion topic than a stack overflow question... Seems like it perfectly fits the closing reason to me.

Comment: @EliteGamer i think in the above commnet you are referring to loxxy :)

Comment: @Mrcoder well, sorry about that. I did edit it. Thank you for telling me :)

Comment: @JAL there are so many questions asked in SO with descriptive answer.some all time popular question.so its your choice to vote for close or not but i dont see a reason.

Comment: @Mrcoder If those questions are popular without any facts or stats, then they were probably just lucky. You turn to SO, when your research fails to provide answers to you. Until you share what you have researched & draw some conclusions out of it, It's totally opinion based.